# what is the fourier transfrom coefficient of $e^{-j\omega t}$?

Tags: fourier-transform

Note:$$j=i=\sqrt{-1}$$

The Fourier Transform series coefficient formula: $$X(jw)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$

We choose $$x(t)=e^{j\omega_0 t}$$

$$X(jw)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{j{w_0-w}t}=\frac{e^{j(w_0-w)\infty}-e^{j(w_0-w)-\infty}}{j(\omega_0-\omega)t}=\frac{\infty-0}{j(\omega_0-\omega)t}$$

I know the right answer is $2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0)$. But how do you see it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Dirac Delta?  What is the inverse Fourier Transform of $2\pi \delta(\omega-\omega_0)$?

Comment: Yes, it's easy to inverse transform the delta function, but not the other way around

Comment: The Dirac Delta is not a function; it is a distribution.  And the FT of $e^{i\omega_o t}$ is not an integral; it's a linear functional.

Comment: Take the FT of $e^{-(|a| +i\omega_0)t}$, $a>0$.  The result should be $\frac{2a}{a^2+(\omega-\omega_0)^2}$.  Now, show for any test function $\phi$ that $$\lim_{a\to 0^+}\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega) \frac{2a}{a^2+(\omega-\omega_0)^2}\,d\omega=\phi(\omega_0)$$